# Objective C class model generator from JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, macos

I need an app or an online converter like [JSON Accelerator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/json-accelerator/id511324989?mt=12) that generates Objective C classes from JSON strings. I had some issues with this app, some JSON's are converted OK others are not. There are a lot of properties, it would take ages to write them down manually and use tools like JSON Model or similar. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are much better off creating a class that can be initialized from an `NSDictionary` and that way you can parse the JSON to an `NSDictionary`, in the traditional way, and then create your class from that dictionary.  You can also create arbitrary instances of the custom class and initialize the properties piece-meal.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property NSString *name;
@property NSUInteger age;

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _name = dict[@"name"];
        _age = [dict[@"age"] unsignedInteger];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: I ended up doing this, tried an online JSON to Objective-C generator online and JSON Accelerator with no results, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use thus toll to get objc object from json

http://www.realmgenerator.eu/

and also you can use these mapper to get our result

https://github.com/aryaxt/OCMapper